# Convert Json Array to Java Array

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert this JSON string into an array:

```
{"result":"success","source":"chat","tag":null,"success":{"message":"%message%","time":%time%,"player":"%player%"}}
```

I would like to output it like this:

```
<%player%> %message%
```

I'm very new to java, I came from PHP where you could just do somthing along the lines of:

```
$result = json_decode($jsonfile, true);
echo "<".$result['success']['player']."> ".$result['success']['message'];

Output: <%player%> %message%
```

Is there an easy way to do this in java?

I searched for some similar topics but I didn't really understand them. Could someone explain this to me like I'm 5?

Comment: Where is your Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) is a good library for JSON in Java.

```java
String jsonString = "{message:'%message%',player:'%player%'}";
JSONObject obj = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonString);    
System.out.println("<" + obj.get("message") + ">" + obj.get("player") );
```

Comment: I've got: `import net.sf.json.*;`at the top with the other imports then your code, I get the errors `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException` when trying to run it, What did I do wrong?

Comment: You must import the dependencies of the JSON-lib as well. It depends on Apache Commons too, so you got that error:

> Json-lib requires (at least) the following dependencies in your classpath:

> jakarta commons-lang 2.5
> jakarta commons-beanutils 1.8.0
> jakarta commons-collections 3.2.1
> jakarta commons-logging 1.1.1
> ezmorph 1.0.6

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel, use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)  - A Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xStream for doing it which has got a very simple API. Just Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always use the following libraries like:**

**-** `Jackson`

**-** `GSON`

**Ok here is the right way to do it Without using any library:**

**Eg:**

`JSONArray jarr = api.giveJsonArr();`

**// giveJsonArr() method is a custom method to give Json Array.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jarr.length(); i++) {

   JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);   // Taking each Json Object

   String mainText = new String();            // fields to hold extracted data
   String provText = new String();
   String couText = new String();
   String fDatu = new String();

   try {
     mainText = jobj.getString("Overview");   // Getting the value of fields
     System.out.println(mainText);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    try {

    JSONObject jProv = jobj.getJSONObject("Provider");
    provText = jProv.getString("Name");
    System.out.println(provText);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    try {
        JSONObject jCou = jobj.getJSONObject("Counterparty");
        couText = jCou.getString("Value");
        System.out.println(couText);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    try {
                String cloText = jobj.getString("ClosingDate");
        fDatu = giveMeDate(cloText);
        System.out.println(fDatu);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see you have many alternatives. Here is a simple one from json.org where you find lots of other alternatives. The one they supply them selves is simple. Here is your example:

```
    String json = "{\"result\":\"success\",\"source\":\"chat\",\"tag\":null,\"success\":{\"message\":\"%message%\",\"time\":%time%,\"player\":\"%player%\"}}";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject success = obj.getJSONObject("success");
    System.out.println("<" + success.get("player") + "> "
                       + success.get("message"));
```