# parse json without node in java

Tags: java, php, json, parsing

my php sends the following json,

```
[
    "x",
    "y",
    "z"
]
```

I am trying to parse this inside java, but I do not have a node to select from.
How do I proceed ?

I am using  the following:

```
JSONArray usernames = json.getJSONArray("What-should-i-put-here");
```

Comment: Its a json Array, so simple iterate. (or provide more information)

Comment: yes I know that. But how to get and put it in a jsonArray in java so that I perform iteration on it.

Comment: You could convert it to a normal array as described [in this stackoverflow question.][1] and [here][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395729/convert-json-array-to-normal-java-array
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286176/convert-json-array-to-java-array

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a simple JSON array. It can be parsed directly with the the library you are using (JSON.org):

```
final String json = "[\"x\", \"y\", \"z\"]";
final JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(array.get(i));
}
```